# Method Not Allowed (POST): /contact/sent/

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

I am getting this method not allowed(post), like I can't post my forms.what could I be doing wrong.I am new to django. Could my url.py be wrong or my form-id is incorrect that doesn't enable the posting of data.I have the forms.py here, not sure if that could be a problem to my problem

views.py

```
class ContactUsView(ContactFormView):
    """ Contact Us Form View """
    form_class = ContactUsForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('messaging:contact_form_sent')


def clear_notification(request):
    """ Clears the notification for a given user"""

    Notifications.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete()
    return redirect(reverse('accounts:dashboard', args=(request.user,)))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'contact/',
        views.ContactUsView.as_view(),
        name='contact_form'),
    path(
        r'contact/sent/',
        TemplateView.as_view(
            template_name='contact_form/contact_form_sent.html'),
        name='contact_form_sent'),
    path(r'clear/', views.clear_notification, name='clear_notification'),
]
```

contact_form.html

```
           <div class="row">
           <form id='ContactUsForm' method='post' action={% url 'messaging:contact_form_sent' %}><br>
            {% csrf_token %}
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                       <input type="text" class="form-control input-upper" id="fullname" placeholder="John Doe" name="fullname">
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                       <input type="email" class="form-control input-upper" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div><br><br>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="form-group">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                       <input type="text" class="form-control input-upper" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-10">
                   <div class="form-group">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                       <textarea class="form-control input-upper" id="message" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
                   </div>
                   {% csrf_token %}
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-send-contact" value="SUBMIT">SEND</button>
               </div>
            </div><br><br>
            </form>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

base-view

```
"""

"""

from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from .forms import ContactForm

try:
    from django.urls import reverse
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse  # pragma: no cover


class ContactFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    recipient_list = None
    template_name = 'contact_form/contact_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # ContactForm instances require instantiation with an
        # HttpRequest.
        kwargs = super(ContactFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})

        # We may also have been given a recipient list when
        # instantiated.
        if self.recipient_list is not None:
            kwargs.update({'recipient_list': self.recipient_list})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse('contact_form_sent')
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `TemplateView` not allowing `POST`, what you need to do is just overwrite the post method.

Exemple :

```
class ContactUsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contact_form/contact_form_sent.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        if context["form"].is_valid():
            print 'POST IS HERE'
        return super(TemplateView, self).render_to_response(context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactUsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = ContactUsEmailForm(self.request.POST or None)  
        context["form"] = form
        return context
```

Comment: I still get this error of  "POST /contact/sent/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0 
HTTP ERROR 405

Answer (score 0):

Your form is posting directly to the confirmation page, contact_form_sent, which is not expecting a post. By doing this it's bypassing the view that is actually processing the post, ContactUsView.

Your form action should be to `messaging:contact_form`.

Comment: When I used that as action messaging:contact_form it returns me back to that same page to fill the contact form.

Comment: Well, where is the processing of the form carried out? What is ContactFormView?

Comment: I have added the forms.py

Comment: I didn't ask for that, I asked for the base view class, ContactFormView.

Comment: posted what i think you might be referring to